# Multiple combined rows in 3 columns inside table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I want to create a table with multiple rows inside 3 columns. It is hard to explain for me, so there is an example:

```css
.min-table{
  width: 300px
}
td p:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
td p {
    min-height: 19px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="min-table">

  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          No
        </th>
        <th>
          Name
        </th>
        <th>
          Date
        </th>
        <th>
          Description
        </th>
        <th>
          Notes
        </th>
        <th>
          Ticket price
        </th>
        <th>
          Tickets left
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          Big breakfast
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>
            03.01.16
          </p>
          <p>
            05.03.16
          </p>
          <p>
            07.04.16
          </p>
          <p>
            01.06.16
          </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>
            Description
          </p>
          <p>
            Description
          </p>
          <p>
            Description
          </p>
          <p>
            Desc
          </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
            01/02/04
          </p>
          <p>
            03/06/06
          </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          $12
        </td>
        <td>
          3500
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          Another event
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>
            03.02.17
          </p>
          <p>
            04.02.17
          </p>
          <p>
            05.02.17
          </p>
          <p>
            06.02.17
          </p>
          <p>
            07.02.17
          </p>
          <p>
            08.02.17
          </p>
          <p>
            09.02.17
          </p>
          <p>
            10.02.17
          </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>
            Description
          </p>
          <p>
            Very very long description
          </p>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
            Desc
          </p>
          <p>
            Description
          </p>
          <p>
            Very very long description
          </p>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
            Desc
          </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
            01/02/04
          </p>
          <p>
            03/06/06
          </p>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
          </p>
          <p>
            01/02/04
          </p>
          <p>
            03/06/06
          </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          $30
        </td>
        <td>
          25
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

No 1 is correct, data are displayed in a right way. But there is a problem, when description is longer. How can I achieve something like no 1 with bigger data? I don't want to create one *td* and inside it another *table*, because of filtering enabled for each column.
In my project I am using DataTables Bundle and Bootstrap 3.

UPDATE:
Data should be formatted like in example, table shows something like events, for one event there should be some (I don't know how much) parties, concerts etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `colspan` and `rowspan` to for your problem take a look at this. I hope this will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:100%" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">No</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Name</th> 
        <th colspan="4">Date</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Description</th>
        <th colspan="2">Code</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Gender</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Date 1</th>
        <th>Date 2</th>
        <th>Date 3</th>
        <th>Date 4</th>
        <th>Code 1</th>
        <th>Code 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Jill Smith</td>
        <td>03.01.16</td>  
        <td>05.07.12</td>
        <td>07.04.07</td>
        <td>01.06.12</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
        <td>ATU985NF97H</td>
        <td>ACE7908HKN1</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>Philippines</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the updated question. Your approach is good, when there is constant amount of dates and descriptions. But it is hard to filter by using DataTables.

Comment: @ptyskju . Please try the following codes above using DataTables. Coz I think it will work.